# Efficient partial concatenation of two lists: numpy

Tags: python, numpy

Say I have two lists, `a1 a2 = [1,2,3,4,4], [4,4,1,2,3]`. I want to "partially concatenate" these with an overlap, where the overlapping values are summed (or a general function is applied element-wise). So, the result will be `[1,2,3,8,8,1,2,3]` in this example.

I can go the easy way:

```
def partial_concat(a1, a2, overlap):
    """Takes 'overlap' many elements from the end of a1 and 
    the 'overlap' many elements from a2 and sums them, 
    then concatenates remaining to create an array of
    len a1 + a2 - overlap"""
    joined = np.add(a1[-overlap:], a2[:overlap])
    return np.concatenate((a1[:-overlap], joined, a2[overlap:]))
```

But, of course, this is not efficient.
Is there a better way making use of numpy's capabilities?

Edit: I should add, I intend to repeatedly apply this function, since I have n lists that need to be partially concatenated to each other.

Comment: That doesn't look bad.  Only timings will say whether something else is better.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `np.concatenate` to extend the two arrays out a bit, just enough to be able to add them together and achieve what you want:

```
def partial_concat(a1, a2, overlap):
    np.concatenate([a1, np.zeros(len(a1) - overlap, dtype=int)]) + np.concatenate([np.zeros(len(a2) - overlap, dtype=int), a2])
```